# Voip app IOS getting error Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=61 "The operation couldn’t be completed. Connection refused

Tags: ios, objective-c, background, stream, voip

I'm trying to create a Voip application as this tutorial 
http://www.raywenderlich.com/29948/backgrounding-for-ios

But when running its getting the error

```
Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=61 "The operation couldn’t be completed. Connection refused
```

When I run the source from tutorial gets same error

I think its the problem with the port assigned. 
How can I solve this problem.
What value to give for port?

Comment: Do you have your own voip server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read his tutorial he mentions this. I'm sure it's your issue.

> Before you run the app, you need a server with which to test it. You
>   can use a handy little utility every Mac already has called netcat
>   that, among other things, allows you to easily create simple
>   text-based servers.

Comment: oh sorry, I just missed that thing